# VueJs component: can't attribute axios reponse to a component variable

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I am new to VueJs with Laravel. I have a component called Event in which a 'read more...' link shoud trigger a function that fetch the event infos from the data base and store the in a variable withing this same component.

Here is the code for my component:

```
<template>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5>
            Title: {{ event.event_name }}
            <span class="pull-right">
                @click=getEventInfo(event.id)>Read more ...</a></span>
        </h5>
        <h5>publised by: {{ event.user.name }}
             <span class="pull-right" v-text="timeFromNow(event.created_at)"></span>
        </h5>

    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <p>{{ event.event_detail }}</p>
        </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
            <p>
            <span>Event for: {{ event.event_to_whom }}</span>
            <span>When: {{  dayOfDate(event.event_when_date) }} {{  event.event_when_date }} at {{event.event_when_time}}</span>
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>


<script>
import moment from 'moment';
export default {
    name: 'app-event',
    props:['event'],
    data() {
        return {
           eventInfo: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        timeFromNow(tmp) {
            return moment(tmp).fromNow();
        },

        dayOfDate(d) {
            let dt = moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD");
            return dt.format('dddd');
        },
        //event.id
        getEventInfo(id){  

            let url = 'events/' + id;

            axios.get(url)
            .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data); //returns data
            this.eventInfo = response.data;
            console.log(this.eventInfo);//returns data
          });

          console.log(this.eventInfo); //returns nothing
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The problem is when I click the 'read more...' link axios returns a response that I can check using console.log(response.data). Hovever when I console.log(this.eventInfo) outside the axios closure, it returns and ampty object.

Am I doing something wrong? Sorry if the question is too basic.

Thanks
L.B

Comment: can you try like [this](https://pastebin.com/JkFi9xVs)?

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, I got a weird object for the last  console.log(self .eventInfo),  "{__ob__: Observer}" with no data in it !

Comment: That's normal. Just don't worry about it. you can display the value `eventInfo` in html and it will be visible. Try it and let me know

Comment: Yes You're right, I think trying to look at the data the wrong way. As you said I just displayed them using html or even better by looking at vueDevtools. Thanks man and have a good day

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are printing logging the property before it is assigned a value.
2. The code below should resolve any errors

   ```
   import moment from 'moment';
   export default {
       name: 'app-event',
       props:['event'],
       data() {
           return {
              eventInfo: {}
           }
       },
       methods: {
           timeFromNow(tmp) {
               return moment(tmp).fromNow();
           },

       dayOfDate(d) {
           let dt = moment(d, "YYYY-MM-DD");
           return dt.format('dddd');
       },
       //event.id
       getEventInfo(id){  
           let url = 'events/' + id;
           axios.get(url)
           .then((response) => this.handleResponse(response.data));
       },
       handleResponse(eventInfo) {
           console.log(eventInfo);
           // do something with the eventInfo...
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your axios call is asynchrone so your outside console.log will be process before the return of the response.

Just keep your code in the   `.then((response) => {  // here i proceed the read more }`